# IE7 table centering bug, any ideas?

Tags: html, email, internet-explorer-7, newsletter, centering

I'm trying to build this html email newsletter but am running into 1 issue with regards to the top table not centering in IE7 and below. IE8, Safari, Chrome, Firefox all render it properly.

I've been trying to fix this one bit for the last couple of hours now and thought that someone here might see a solution to this.

I think rather than posting all my markup here (tables, yay!) I will just post the link below and if you can, it would be great if you could open it and take a look at what's going on.

**Link:** http://domainz.dev.supply.net.nz/newsletter/

Many thanks,

Jannis

Answer (score 1):

If you're coding an Email Newsletter I think you should rely on `align="center"` and basically code like you're in 2000.

Use the `style` attribute instead of external CSS since some email clients do not support it properly, dont use `p`'s but `br`'s and textnodes, etc.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I generally do, the odd thing is that the linked newsletter (after moving styles inline, done on import via campaignmonitor) renders perfectly across all email clients except that the header is not centered and sits left aligned in Outlook Express and Outlook 2003. Any ideas why this is the only spot where it breaks?